# Getting undefined function public_path() error in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to upload image in lumen. I got some examples and when i tried to implement it, got below error
`<!-- Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\public_path() (500 Internal Server Error) -->`

Just want to confirm is this function got changed or do i need to include helper file.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of Laravel helpers don't exist in Lumen including `public_path()` and `storage_path()` you can include both methods in your Lumen project by creating a `helpers.php` file in your `App` directory or wherever you want and autoload that file in your `composer.json` files like so

```
"autoload": {
   "files": [
      "app/helpers.php"
   ],
   ....
  }
},
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 5):

Laravel helper.php file  in your App directory or wherever you want and autoload that file in your composer.json files

*composer.json*

```
"autoload": {
   "files": [
      "app/helpers.php"
   ],
   ....
  }
},
```

*helper.php*

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('config_path'))
{
        /**
        * Return the path to config files
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function config_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->getConfigurationPath(rtrim($path, ".php"));
        }
}

if(!function_exists('public_path'))
{

        /**
        * Return the path to public dir
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function public_path($path=null)
        {
                return rtrim(app()->basePath('public/'.$path), '/');
        }
}

if(!function_exists('storage_path'))
{

        /**
        * Return the path to storage dir
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function storage_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->storagePath($path);
        }
}

if(!function_exists('database_path'))
{

        /**
        * Return the path to database dir
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function database_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->databasePath($path);
        }
}

if(!function_exists('resource_path'))
{

        /**
        * Return the path to resource dir
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function resource_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->resourcePath($path);
        }
}

if(!function_exists('lang_path'))
{

        /**
        * Return the path to lang dir
        * @param null $str
        * @return string
        */
        function lang_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->getLanguagePath($path);
        }
}

if ( ! function_exists('asset'))
{
    /**
     * Generate an asset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('elixir'))
{
    /**
     * Get the path to a versioned Elixir file.
     *
     * @param  string  $file
     * @return string
     */
    function elixir($file)
    {
        static $manifest = null;
        if (is_null($manifest))
        {
            $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path().'/build/rev-manifest.json'), true);
        }
        if (isset($manifest[$file]))
        {
            return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('auth'))
{
    /**
     * Get the available auth instance.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */
    function auth()
    {
        return app('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard');
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('bcrypt'))
{
    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return string
     */
    function bcrypt($value, $options = array())
    {
        return app('hash')->make($value, $options);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('redirect'))
{
    /**
     * Get an instance of the redirector.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $to
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
    {
        if (is_null($to)) return app('redirect');
        return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('response'))
{
    /**
     * Return a new response from the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $content
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response|\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory
     */
    function response($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = array())
    {
        $factory = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory');
        if (func_num_args() === 0)
        {
            return $factory;
        }
        return $factory->make($content, $status, $headers);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('secure_asset'))
{
    /**
     * Generate an asset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return string
     */
    function secure_asset($path)
    {
        return asset($path, true);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('secure_url'))
{
    /**
     * Generate a HTTPS url for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @return string
     */
    function secure_url($path, $parameters = array())
    {
        return url($path, $parameters, true);
    }
}


if ( ! function_exists('session'))
{
    /**
     * Get / set the specified session value.
     *
     * If an array is passed as the key, we will assume you want to set an array of values.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function session($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) return app('session');
        if (is_array($key)) return app('session')->put($key);
        return app('session')->get($key, $default);
    }
}


if ( ! function_exists('cookie'))
{
    /**
     * Create a new cookie instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  int     $minutes
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $domain
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @param  bool    $httpOnly
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie
     */
    function cookie($name = null, $value = null, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
    {
        $cookie = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\Factory');
        if (is_null($name))
        {
            return $cookie;
        }
        return $cookie->make($name, $value, $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
    }
}
```

finally run the command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```